# Redundancy in post-increment overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

```
// The following operator++() represents overloading of pre-increment 
MyIncrDecrClass& operator++()  
{ 
    ++this->m_nCounter; 
    return *this; 
} 

// Passing dummy int argument is to mention overloading of post-increment  
MyIncrDecrClass& operator++(int)  
{ 
    this->m_nCounter++; 
    return *this; 
}
```

So this is how a post and pre increment operator are implemented, but in my case I can't really implement it like that, so this is what I did:

```
VLongInt& VLongInt::operator++()
{
    ... //BUILD TEMP vector
    this->vec = temp;
    return *this;
}

VLongInt& VLongInt::operator++(int)
{
    this->vec = this.vec; //seems unnecessary
    ... //BUILD TEMP vector
    this->vec = temp
    return *this;
}
```

Is there anything wrong? It seems that both should be implemented the same way. Only the header file should differ, right?

Comment: It sounds like your code works and you just want to know if you wrote it wrong.  This might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It all depends on what you want the increment operator to signify for your class. But it looks wrong to me - either way your argument should be modified - but in one case you should return the original, not the modified version. And you don't distinguish between function signatures - does this even compile?

Comment: In the second block of code you wrote two functions that have identical names, return types, and parameters.  Maybe I don't know enough about C++, but how is the compiler supposed to distinguish those two definitions?

Comment: @DavidGrayson - my point exactly!

Comment: "I can't really implement it like that" -- May I ask why?

Comment: In both of your code blocks you're not defining the postfix increment correctly. In both cases both your prefix and postfix increment do the same thing (or they would if your second block actually compiled). The postfix increment is supposed to return the old value, not `*this`.

Comment: the old value? then it wouldn't increment, no?

Comment: @user2967016, the value of `++n` is the old value of `n` incremented by one; the value of `n++` is the old value of `n`. In both cases, afterwards `n` has been incremented.

Comment: so when you return the old value, the system takes that old value and then update it using the calling object this? just by looking at the code, we can't really know that's what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of overloading of the postincrement operator is wrong.

Intsead of

```
// Passing dummy int argument is to mention overloading of post-increment  
MyIncrDecrClass& operator++(int)  
{ 
    this->m_nCounter++; 
    return *this; 
}
```

there should be

```
// Passing dummy int argument is to mention overloading of post-increment  
MyIncrDecrClass operator ++( int )  
{
    MyIncrDecrClass tmp( *this );

    ++this->m_nCounter; 

    return tmp; 
}
```

ALso your problem is totally unclear. You defined in fact the same operator twice

```
VLongInt& VLongInt::operator++()
{
    //...
    return *this;
}

VLongInt& VLongInt::operator++()
{
    //...
    return *this;
}
```

I do not see a difference. Moreover you did not show your class definition and as the result nothing can be said about your problem. It is unknown.

At least as you said yourself your postincrement operator should be declared with a dummy parameter of type `int`. And it has to return a temporary object.

```
VLongInt  VLongInt::operator ++( int )
```

or

```
const VLongInt  VLongInt::operator ++( int )
```

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be:  VLongInt& VLongInt::operator++(int)

Comment: @user2967016 It is a wrong declaration because you return the object itself. So there is no difference between your postincrement and preincrement operators.

Comment: Ok so I should do something like this? this = original; ... this->vec = temp ... return original   ????

Comment: If I return the original this, would that make it post-increment? Can you explain the inner-working of the code, so to speak? C++ is sort of cryptic.

Comment: @user2967016 post increment means that you have to return a copy of the object before changing its state. If you return *this then you return already modified object. All is written in my post how the operators should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong?

Yes, with your code you are violating the ODR (one definition rule). Which is defined in § 3.2/1 as:

> No translation unit shall contain more than one definition of any variable, function, class type, enumeration type, or template.

You should define these two functions instead:

```
VLongInt& VLongInt::operator++();
const VLongInt VLongInt::operator++(int);
```

Specifically, please, note that the post increment operator should return either `const T` or `T` (with `T` being your class type).

Comment: is it something really necessary (something that may change the output) or something I should do if I was to become a professional programmer?